# Microsoft Outlook 2007 - Disable Reply to All Button

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, email

I keep getting email which was sent to a group but I need to reply to only one person. unfortunately I am a little trigger happy with the "reply to all" button and need to do something about it.

Is there a way to either:

- ask for confirmation after pressing the "RTA" (reply to all) button
- disable the RTA button
- remove the RTA button
- make the RTA button jump to the other side of the screen when the mouse goes over it
- make the system "beep" noise when the mouse hovers over the RTA button
- *[you can see where this is going ...]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm adding an answer to my own question! Here is a solution how to [prevent someone else from doing it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToEasilyDisableReplyToAllAndForwardInOutlook.aspx).

Comment: Well, I knew that Scott Hanselman was smarter than me...

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Erm, some random thoughts...

- Use a post-it note. Either a reminder
  above the screen or a piece just the
  size of the RTA button to cover it
  up. Yes, might get in the way of
  other apps.
- Use gmail or another email app. You
  can have messages sent from Outlook
  to gmail and (I think) reply via
  Outlook. The other interface might
  make you think more slowly about
  which button you want.
- Maybe a filter/rule is possible. If
  the sender of the group message is
  always the same then, I dunno, "if
  recipient = personX, then don't send
  and show error message "Did you send
  to all, you crazy fool?""
- Apply some other memory and learning
  strategies. Break up the automatic
  workflow somehow until you have
  trained yourself out of the habit.

None very convincing I'm afraid, but you might need some kind of "creative" solution.